# Creating subclass entities in doctrine with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to create a user system in my symfony2 project where I have two types of users; buyers and sellers.  Both are users, so it would make sense for them to extend a basic user class.

```
// Acme/UserBundle/Entity/BaseUser
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseUser implements UserInterface, \Serializable {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $region;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_validated", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isValidated;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->isValidated = false;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     * All users must return the role: ROLE_USER
     */
    public function getRoles() {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials() {

    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     * We only need to return the ID because you can use the ID to load the rest from the database.
     */
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
            $this->id,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    // Getters and Setters removed
}
```

And then there is a buyer to extend that class:

```
// Acme/UserBundle/Entity/Buyer
/**
 * ORM\Entity
 * ORM\Table(name="buyer")
 */
class Buyer extends BaseUser {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_of_birth", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $dateOfBirth;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $gender;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="mobile_number", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $mobileNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="receive_newsletter", type="boolean", length=255)
     */
    protected $receiveNewsletter;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     * Buyers have their own buyer role
     */
    public function getRoles() {
        return array_push(parent::getRoles(), 'ROLE_BUYER');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the doctrine tool to auto-generate the getter/setter methods within Buyer.php but I'm getting the error message:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme/UserBundle/Entity/Buyer
Generating entity "Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Buyer"



  [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
  Class "Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Buyer" sub class of "Acme\UserBundle\En
  tity\BaseUser" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.



doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

I haven't tried to implement the methods myself, create the schema, and persist a buyer object yet.  I figure if the tool says there is a problem, then there's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you forgot "@" before "ORM" in buyer annotations

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple...  I was sure there was actually a problem!

Comment: Cyprain, please answer the question below to get credit for this. :).

Comment: :) It happens to any of us! Take care!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot "@" before "ORM" in buyer annotations